# Mailchimp - Add a new subscriber (JQuery + AJAX)

Tags: javascript, ajax, mailchimp

I've been trying to connect to MailChimp 3.0 API through the JS function below:

```
    var mailchimp_api_key = (api key as in my account);
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();

    if(name.indexOf(' ') != 0) {
        var fname = name.substr(0, name.indexOf(' '));
        var lname = name.substr(name.indexOf(' ') + 1);
    } else {
        fname = name;
    }

    var mailchimp = JSON.stringify({
        email_address: email,
        status: 'subscribed',
        merge_fields: {
            FNAME: fname,
            LNAME: lname
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://(my server in MC).api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/(list id)/members/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: mailchimp,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        error: function(res, text){
            console.log('Err', res);
        },
        success: function(res){
            console.log('Success', res);
        },
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("api:" + mailchimp_api_key))
        }
    });
```

My problem is that I've been getting an 401 error, and nothing I do correct this.

I'm local and not using a server.

Comment: This is a bad idea. You're giving the world access to your api key. Additionally, setting a contentType and a header makes no sense when making a JSONP request (research what a JSONP request is please. Here's a hint: it doesn't use XHR)

Comment: I understand the problem, but I need to do this for now... I believe in just a little while I'll be able to put the server on... Until then this module won't be open for public use, nonetheless...

Comment: What you are trying to do isn't possible. You'll have to use the JSON type, and with that you'll run into CORS problems that you cannot resolve without a server of your own.

Comment: There's likely another option, using a POST request that doesn't require your api key to subscribe to your newsletter. I've never used mailchimp so i can't be sure if they do, but the provider i use does offer that.